# My GoogleAnalytics can't showed real time after disable then enable the App-level Opt Out

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to disable and enable GoogleAnalytics dynamically use a button with App-level Opt Out. I set the "on"/"off" value on SharedPreference variable, and set its listener like Google's [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#opt-out).
When GA is enable, it shows logs like this:

```
10-15 12:22:58.001: V/GAV3(29429): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: cd6=android,  ul=en-ph,  cd1=logout,  ht=1413350577995,  sr=720x1280,  aid=jp.co.mti.yomeljp,  cid=e931c34c-1844-4542-9a04-92cf25133153,  av=3.1.0,  v=1,  t=appview,  an=m.book(rc),  tid=UA-49102867-3,  _u=.r3qKKK-AL,  cd=yl_help,
```

And when GA is disable, it shows log like this:

```
10-15 12:22:00.743: V/GAV3(1356): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: clearHits called
10-15 12:22:00.853: V/GAV3(1356): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: PowerSaveMode initiated.
10-15 12:22:01.873: V/GAV3(1356): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: clearHits called
10-15 12:22:02.003: V/GAV3(1356): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: clearHits called
10-15 12:22:02.013: V/GAV3(1356): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: clearHits called
```

When I enable GA, the log shows that it sending hit to store path. But the problem is, I can't see it result on the web. Did I miss something? any clue will help, thank you.

I use GAV3, I have set it to the correct UA agent, and the WiFi connection is good.